# Как добыть размер загруженной браузером страницы из пользовательского скрипта

Tags: javascript, userjs

Есть ли способ быстрее, чем обойти дерево документа, получая у узлов размер (если такой метод есть(предполагаю, хоть у части, должен быть)) или информацию,
по которой он определим.